# How to inject variables from .env file in docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Why my .env variable is not injected into my docker-compose.yml ?

I have a folder with a:

.env file:

```
NPM_TOKEN=<NPM_TOKEN>
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  msaccountpublic:
    build:
      context: ../app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: ${NPM_TOKEN}
    command: npm start
```

And i get a 401 (which means the token has not been injected) when i run `docker-compose up --build`

However, it works when i directly save the value into the `docker-compose.yml`:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  msaccountpublic:
    build:
      context: ../app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        NPM_TOKEN: <NPM_TOKEN> (the value directly hard coded here)
    command: npm start
```

However i would like to commit the docker-compose.yml without my personnal credentials

Comment: you can pass the build-arg via 
`docker-compose build --build-arg NPM_TOKEN=123`

Comment: Yes, but is there any way to store it in an external file ?

Comment: My minimal example works exactly like what you described. Can you add `RUN echo "$NPM_TOKEN"` to you Dockerfile in the beginning and test if it really cannot read the token?

Comment: oh and just to verify, you're `.env` file is in the same folder as the `docker-compose.yml`? And you're executing `docker-compose up --build` in this folder?

Comment: RUN echo "$NPM_TOKEN" doesn't print anything
Yes exactly this is what i try.

Comment: When i run `NPM_TOKEN=<MY_TOKEN> docker-compose up --build` it works, it is really like the .env variables are not injected to the args section...

Comment: Hi @Ludo, I was in the same situations whereby my `.env` was not in the same directory as the `docker-compose.yml` file. `docker-compose` wont be able to pull from an `.env` if it is not in the same directory so as bad as it is you will need to add another `.env` in the same directory as the `docker-compose`.

More information here: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4764#issuecomment-488645209